# wmpPlayer Repeat Forever

Tags: vb.net, winforms, wmp

I have a windows media player object embedded in my form and it's set to auto-play a video.
I want that video to loop forever, but can't figure out how!

Right-clicking the object in design view brings up settings and includes "Play count" but setting it to 0 won't work. It reverts to 1 as soon as the properties window is closed. Also it won't accept -1. The max setting is 999 which isn't enough as the video will only loop for a few hours.

This is how I am manipulating controls:

```vb
    wmpPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play()

    wmpPlayer.Ctlcontrols.pause()

    wmpPlayer.URL = ofdOpen.FileName 'Play

  ' This does NOT work to make repeat forever!...
  ' wmpPlayer.settings.playCount() = 0
```

- I've tried catching the 'PlayStateChanged' event like so:

  ```
  Private Sub wmpPlayer_PlayStateChange_1(sender As Object, e As AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent) Handles wmpPlayer.PlayStateChange
  If e.newState = 8 Then
      wmpPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play()
  End If
  '0 = Undefined
  '1 = Stopped (by User)
  '2 = Paused
  '3 = Playing
  '4 = Scan Forward
  '5 = Scan Backwards
  '6 = Buffering
  '7 = Waiting
  '8 = Media Ended
  '9 = Transitioning
  '10 = Ready
  '11 = Reconnecting
  '12 = Last
  End Sub
  ```

But I'm not sure if this method always works. I left my program running overnight on two machines and this morning one was still running but the other had stopped somehow.

Comment: Wow, you must really like that video.  Depending on how you embedded the WMP, it may also fire an event when it stops playing in which case you can tell it to play another 999 times.

Comment: It's for a demo, so it will be set up and left to run days. Various people will come by and take a gander at it and then move on. I'll look for that event, thanks!

Comment: more info here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19734422/1070452  he was using AxWMP I think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want that video to loop forever, but can't figure out how!

Just set the "Loop" mode property in settings to true:

```
wmpPlayer.settings.setMode("Loop", True)
```

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow, thanks. Hans commented a solution earlier that worked for me, but the answer he commented on has been deleted! Oh well. I'll try this, if it works than it's simpler so hopefully it will help others.

Comment: It worked in when I tested it earlier today.  Hopefully it works for you as well...  =)

Comment: Excellent, works like a charm. Thanks! I don't know why someone down-voted, this precious tid bit of information is not easy to find!

Comment: Does not work for me for some reason. It says there is an unexpected end to statement, yet when I remove the brackets it works somewhat, just cuts off in the middle of the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Or try with excel vba

```
WindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode "Loop", True
```